# How to remove the decimal part of columns data in table using PDF::Table perl module

Tags: perl, pdf, pdf-generation, perl-module

I want the data in tables without decimal values. I searched the options for doing the same in PDF::Table and PDF::API2 perl modules since i'm making use of these modules in my code. But i did not find any options. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Please show the code you are using to generate that table and some example data and example output.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just map the data through some function that removes the decimals. Here's some code, based on the [synopsis of the PDF::Table POD](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::Table).

```
use PDF::API2;
use PDF::Table;

my $pdftable = new PDF::Table;
my $pdf = new PDF::API2(-file => "table_of_lorem.pdf");
my $page = $pdf->page;

# some data to layout
my $some_data =[
    [ 0, 0.1 .. 0.9 ],
    [ 1, 1.1 .. 1.9 ],
    #... and so on
];

$left_edge_of_table = 50;
# build the table layout
$pdftable->table(
     # required params
     $pdf,
     $page,
     remove_decimals($some_data), # here's our function
     x => $left_edge_of_table,
     w => 495,
     start_y => 500,
     start_h => 300,
     # some optional params
     next_y  => 750,
     next_h  => 500,
     padding => 5,
     padding_right => 10,
     background_color_odd  => "gray",
     background_color_even => "lightblue", #cell background color for even rows
);
```

And somewhere else we define the function `remove_decimals`.

```
sub remove_decimals {
  my ( $data ) = @_;

  # we are making copies so we don't alter the original data
  my $new_data = []; 
  foreach my $row ( @$data ) {
    push @$new_data, map { int } @$row;
  }

  return $new_data;
}
```

Please note that *this code is untested*.

Comment: I don't want to remove the decimals. Just want to round up the value. For instance, if the value is 10.83 it should convert to 11.

Comment: Any perl PDF module to round up the numeric data??

Comment: Your question says *How to remove the decimal part*. You can do rounding with basic Perl. `sprintf '%.0f', 10.83` will yield 11. See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html. Also **please read the [faq#howtoask]**.